# How to initialize an object from one method to another method within a class?

Tags: c#, class, methods

In a class, I have 2 methods. In method1 I created an object, but I can't use the same object in method2.

Why? Please help with a simple example.

The coding is too big, so I have given the layout

```
public class Sub
{
}

public class DataLoader
{
    public void process1()
    {
        Sub obj = new Sub();
    }

    public void process2()
    {
        // here I can't use the object
    }
}
```

Comment: Therin I had posted the code layout.

Comment: It's been answered. So accept whichever works for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is [**scope**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). A *local variable* can only be accessed from the block it is declared in. To access it from multiple methods, add a *field* or pass it to the other method as a *parameter*.

**Field:**

```
class YourClass
{
    object yourObject;

    void Method1()
    {
        yourObject = new object();
    }

    void Method2()
    {
        int x = yourObject.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Parameter:**

```
class YourClass
{
    void Method1()
    {
        Method2(new object());
    }

    void Method2(object theObject)
    {
        int x = theObject.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code, using `object` makes sense. But I think it should be stressed out that using fields or parameters of type `object` is not the right solution most of the time.

Comment: absolutely. Except when you need a synchronization lock ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use member variables in your class.

```
public class DataLoader
{
    private Sub mySub;

    public void Process1()
    {
        mySub = new Sub();
    }

    public void Process2()
    {
        if(mySub == null) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Called Process2 before Process1!");            

        // use mySub here
    }
}
```

Read up on different variable scopes (specifically, instance variables in this case). You can also pass your object as a parameter, like codesparkle mentioned in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12437877).

Comment: I can't understand Lear.  Can you explain it?

Comment: @user1671639 I updated my code to use your example. Does that help? If not, what part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (without seeing your code) is that the object created in `Method1` doesn't have any visibility, or scope, in `Method2`.

There are already some good answers here that show you how to solve your specific problem. But the real answer here is to familiarize yourself generally with the concept of *Scope*. It's a fundamental part of programming and learning more about it will help you tons.

There are many good articles and videos on the subject. This [video](http://lecturesnippets.com/2011/07/06/visual-c-2010-variable-scope/) is a great start. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the object as a class field, then you can access it from every method of your class.