# Cannot access variable in another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, scope

I have tried the other solutions on stackoverflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437798/how-to-initialize-an-object-from-one-method-to-another-method-within-a-class) but I still cannot manage to get this to work.  I just want to be able to access the customer object in these two methods, but it is always null in the last method.  What am I missing here?

```
public class Administration_CustomerDisplay : Page
{
    private Customer customer;

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = "test";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(customer);   //Why is this null ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The customer object is only created when the droplist changes... then your pages renders after the droplist change and the customer object is gone.

You would need to persist the object in the session if you want it to be available after a button click.

Comment: Got it. And the syntax for the session that worked for me was `HttpContext.Current.Session["customer"] = customer;` The answer from @Jumpei helped me put it all together but his syntax for using Session was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in a Windows application, your Page object doesn't just sit in memory the whole time.  That object gets created on the server each time the user makes a request.  Each event is going to correspond to a different request and therefore a different Page object.  The second object doesn't know anything about the first object and the value of its `customer` field.  The second object never has its `customer` field set so it is always null.

If you want a value to be persisted between requests then you have to use a session variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should save the instance in `Session` like below.

```
public partial class Administration_CustomerDisplay : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Customer customer;

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = "test";
        HttpContext.Current.Session["customer"] = customer;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customer = HttpContext.Current.Session["customer"];
        Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);   //Why is this null ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Session is a dictionary, not a method.

Comment: Yeah, that was my hunch, but decided to make sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Obiviously the cuntomer must be global variable.

```
public class Administration_CustomerDisplay : Page
{
    private Customer customer = new Customer();

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           customer.Name = "test";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(customer);   //Why is this null ?
     }
}
```